# Accesing C++ model from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have created a minimal working example. I hope it will be understandable. My problem is that I cannot create a model for my top level item in order to access items further. This is how the classes objects architecture looks like:

```
CTop
    x times CMiddle
        y times CBottom
```

This is a tree architecture. Here is the code:

CBottom.h:

```
#ifndef CBOTTOM_H
#define CBOTTOM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

class CBottom : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:

    CBottom(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {

    }

    CBottom(const QString& name, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qmlRegisterType<CBottom>("Bottom", 1, 0, "Bottom");
        m_name = name;
    }

    QString name()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    void setName(const QString& name)
    {
        if (name != m_name)
        {
            m_name = name;
            emit nameChanged();
        }
    }

signals:

    void nameChanged();

private:

    QString m_name;
};

#endif // CBOTTOM_H
```

CMiddle.h:

```
#ifndef CMIDDLE_H
#define CMIDDLE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QVector>

#include "cbottom.h"

class CMiddle : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:

    CMiddle(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {

    }

    CMiddle(const QString& name, const QStringList& bottoms, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qmlRegisterType<CMiddle>("Middle", 1, 0, "Middle");
        m_name = name;

        foreach (auto bottom, bottoms)
        {
            m_bottoms.append(new CBottom(bottom));
        }
    }

    QString name()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    void setName(const QString& name)
    {
        if (name != m_name)
        {
            m_name = name;
            emit nameChanged();
        }
    }

signals:

    void nameChanged();

private:

    QString m_name;
    QVector<CBottom*> m_bottoms;
};

#endif // CMIDDLE_H
```

CTop.h:

```
#ifndef CTOP_H
#define CTOP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

#include "cmiddle.h"

class CTop : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    CTop(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {

    }

    CTop(const QStringList& middles, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qmlRegisterType<CTop>("Top", 1, 0, "Top");
        int i = 0;

        foreach (auto middle, middles)
        {
            QStringList bottoms;
            bottoms.append("A" + QString(i));
            bottoms.append("B" + QString(i));
            bottoms.append("C" + QString(i));
            i++;

            m_middles.append(new CMiddle(middle, bottoms));
        }
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVector<CMiddle*>& middles()
    {
        return m_middles;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE CMiddle* middle(const int index)
    {
        return m_middles[index];
    }

private:

    QVector<CMiddle*> m_middles;

};

#endif // CTOP_H
```

main.c:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "ctop.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList middles;
    middles.append("FirstMiddle");
    middles.append("SecondMiddle");

    CTop* top = new CTop(middles);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("theTop", QVariant::fromValue(top));

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import Top 1.0

Window
{
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Repeater
    {
        model: theTop.middles();
        delegate: txtComp;
    }

    Component
    {
        id: txtComp;

        Text
        {
            text: name;
        }
    }

}
```

The question is: Why isn't the name of the one of the `CMiddle` objects displayed in the QML code? I wanted to obtain the `CMiddle` components (to act as a model) from the exported to QML `CTop` components. If this code worked, I would then go further and made another model for accessing the `CBottom` objects within each `CMiddle` object.

For instance, I noticed that this QML code works:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import Top 1.0

Window
{
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Repeater
    {
        model: theTop;
        delegate: txtComp;
    }

    Component
    {
        id: txtComp;

        Text
        {
            text: middle(0).name;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

It doesnt make much sense, but shows that the `CTop` component is exposed correctly to the QML part.

Why cant the output `Qvector` of `CMiddle` pointers act as a model in the QML part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML does not know `QList<CMiddle *>`, instead you should use `QList<QObject *>`:

**CTop.h**

```cpp
// ...
Q_INVOKABLE QList<QObject*> middles(){
    QList<QObject*> objects;
    for(CMiddle *m : qAsConst(m_middles)){
        objects << m;
    }
    return objects;
}
// ...
```

Also another error is that top should not necessarily be a pointer, and you can pass it without using `QVariant::fromValue()` since it is a `QObject`:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// ...
CTop top(middles);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("theTop", &top);
```

Also in a Repeater to obtain the item of the model using [modelData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#repeaters):

**main.qml**

```
//...
Component{
    id: txtComp;
    Text{
        text: modelData.name
    }
}
//...
```

---

<sub>The complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55857689)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have updated the code in question body with your hints. I was using `QVector` instead of `QList` but it seems like only `QList` container can be used in order for the QML to accept it... At this point my problem is that on the QML part the `name` is nod defined. I am getting this error twice: `qrc:/main.qml:24: ReferenceError: name is not defined` so it means there are 2 objects at least just like it should. Do you know why would name be not accesible?

Comment: @Bremen It seems that you have applied a solution that I have not indicated. I have not said that the solution is to change QVector to QList, also the modification should not be done in CMiddle. The solution is to copy my code in CTop. On the other hand I have provided my code tested in a link that is in my question, try it and tell me if it works: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55857689

Comment: I must have mispasted something- now its similar to your code. As for my problem, I did not know one has to use `modelData` keyword before accessing the exposed fields. After doing so (like in your code), it works! Thank you.

Comment: @Bremen I think I forgot to point out, in a moment I will add it to my answer, for that reason I always try to provide my test code for the OP to analyze it.

Comment: Also, `Qvector` really doesnt work as the container for the QML part. It has to be `QList`